# Issues with Password Masking in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to follow the steps found in the following link for masking the input of a password in 64-bit Excel:  https://wellsr.com/vba/2016/excel/mask-your-password-with-this-vba-inputbox/

When I try running my macro (see module listed beow), my file just closes out.  I've tagged the spot where the code crashes.  Can somebody help me resolve this issue?  I'm not nearly skilled enough to figure this out on my own.

Contents of my Module:

```
'----------------------------------
'API CONSTANTS FOR PRIVATE INPUTBOX
'----------------------------------
Private Declare PtrSafe Function CallNextHookEx Lib "user32" (ByVal hHook As LongPtr, ByVal ncode As Long, ByVal wParam As LongPtr, lParam As Any) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetModuleHandle Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetModuleHandleA" (ByVal lpModuleName As String) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetWindowsHookEx Lib "user32" Alias "SetWindowsHookExA" (ByVal idHook As Long, ByVal lpfn As LongPtr, ByVal hmod As LongPtr, ByVal dwThreadId As Long) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function UnhookWindowsHookEx Lib "user32" (ByVal hHook As LongPtr) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function SendDlgItemMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendDlgItemMessageA" (ByVal hDlg As LongPtr, ByVal nIDDlgItem As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As LongPtr, ByVal lParam As LongPtr) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetClassName Lib "user32" Alias "GetClassNameA" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal nMaxCount As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetCurrentThreadId Lib "kernel32" () As Long

'Constants to be used in our API functions
Private Const EM_SETPASSWORDCHAR = &HCC
Private Const WH_CBT = 5
Private Const HCBT_ACTIVATE = 5
Private Const HC_ACTION = 0

Private hHook As LongPtr

'----------------------------------
'PRIVATE PASSWORDS FOR INPUTBOX
'----------------------------------

'////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
'Password masked inputbox
'Allows you to hide characters entered in a VBA Inputbox.
'
'Code written by Daniel Klann
'March 2003
'////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Public Function NewProc(ByVal lngCode As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As Long) As Long
    Dim RetVal
    Dim strClassName As String, lngBuffer As Long

    If lngCode < HC_ACTION Then
        NewProc = CallNextHookEx(hHook, lngCode, wParam, lParam)
        Exit Function
    End If

    strClassName = String$(256, " ")
    lngBuffer = 255

    If lngCode = HCBT_ACTIVATE Then    'A window has been activated

        RetVal = GetClassName(wParam, strClassName, lngBuffer)

        If Left$(strClassName, RetVal) = "#32770" Then  'Class name of the Inputbox

            'This changes the edit control so that it display the password character *.
            'You can change the Asc("*") as you please.
            SendDlgItemMessage wParam, &H1324, EM_SETPASSWORDCHAR, Asc("*"), &H0
        End If

    End If

    'This line will ensure that any other hooks that may be in place are

'called correctly.
    CallNextHookEx hHook, lngCode, wParam, lParam

End Function

Function InputBoxDK(Prompt, Title) As String
#If VBA7 Then
    Dim lngModHwnd As LongPtr
#End If
Dim lngThreadID As Long
    lngThreadID = GetCurrentThreadId
    lngModHwnd = GetModuleHandle(vbNullString)
'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
MsgBox ("Breaks on next line")
'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CBT, AddressOf NewProc, lngModHwnd, lngThreadID)
    InputBoxDK = InputBox(Prompt, Title)
    UnhookWindowsHookEx hHook
End Function

Sub Test_InputBoxDK()
x = InputBoxDK("Enter your Password.", "Password Required")
End Sub
```

Comment: Not super familiar with using API calls, but I believe there are differences between the 32-bit and 64-bit ones, so that's where I would start.